# Strange C construction encountered in academic paper

Tags: c, function

The code states:

```
void (* log_msg)(char *msg)
    =printf;

void change_and_log(int *buffer, int offset, int value){
    buffer[offset] = value;
    log_msg("changed");
}
```

I'm most concerned with the first part:

Firstly, what does the signature `void (* log_msg)(char *msg)` mean?  Is this code simply mapping the function `log_msg` to `printf`?  In that case, why is the function name `(* log_msg)` and not simply `log_msg`?

Comment: I would consider this code dodgy, because calls to `log_msg()` with an argument that contains a `%` formatting instruction will produce undefined behaviour (`log_msg()` has no way to provide additional arguments expected by `printf()`, unless your compiler is set to ignore function prototypes).

Comment: @Greg might have been useful to mention that this code was in a paper about security flaws in code.

Comment: I see. Was it talking about that one specifically? :)

Comment: The idea was to provide an unexpected `offset` to the function `change_and_log` and hence override `log_msg`, but I wasn't quite sure what that meant without knowing that `log_msg` was actually a function pointer and not a function.

Comment: It sounds like the example was more about bounds checking than unexpected `printf()` parameters. Which is fair, since it's only an example, but I would probably have chosen `puts()` or something instead.

Comment: Even without any `%` in the message, this code has undefined behavior. You cannot call a variadic-arguments function through a function pointer whose type is to a non-variadic-arguments function. Also the return type is wrong. `int (* log_msg)(char *msg, ...)=printf;` would fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html).

The type of a function pointer is `R (*)(Args...)`, where `R` and `Args...` are replaced with the return type and arguments, if any. It is read as "a pointer to a function that takes arguments `Args...` and returns `R`."

Your code would read easier as:

```
// print_function is a type that is a function pointer
typedef void (*print_function)(char *msg); 

// log_msg is a variable of the type print_function: it points to a function
print_function log_msg = printf; // point to printf
```

And later, it's just calling that function via a function pointer.

Answer (score 6):

`void (* log_msg)(char *msg)` is actually a function pointer. You could view this as

```
typedef void (*LoggerFunctionPointer)(char* msg);

LoggerFunctionPointer log_msg = printf;
```

Yes, it maps `log_msg` to `printf`, but no, `log_msg` isn't a function, but a pointer that points to a function `printf`.

Using a function pointer has the advantage that the `log_msg` can be switched at runtime. For example, you could provide a switch in the interface that

```
void no_log_msg(char* msg) {}
...
if (enable_debug) {
  log_msg = printf;
} else {
  log_msg = no_log_msg;
}
```

then, without changing other source code, all logging can be inhibited.

---

(BTW, the sample code is incorrect because the signature of `printf` is `int printf(const char*, ...)`. To avoid the implicit cast, `log_msg` should be declared as

```
int (*log_msg)(const char*, ...) = printf;
```

)

Comment: Exactly. The "academic paper" made a rather serious error. You can't call `printf` as an `void (char *)` function. Basically, every single type in the pointer declaration is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The top two lines are establishing a function *pointer* (hence the *), the function is named log_msg, and it's then set to point to printf - after which a call to log_msg ends up calling printf.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

`log_msg` is a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html), in particular a "pointer to a function taking a `char *` and returning `void`". In this case it's just used as an alias for `printf` (but could point to any function with the same arguments and return type).

The syntax for function pointers in C can be pretty intimidating at first.